# plt.scatter() возвращает ошибку: "ValueError: x and y must be the same size"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Стоит задача по визуализации данных с файла типа.csv. Я пытаюсь сделать это в виде разброса (scatter), но никак не получается. По оси `Х` отобразить `position`, а по `Y` отобразить датчики (252 шт.) `detector_0`...`detector_251`.

Все мои попытки выдают ошибку `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`. В данных имеются колонки `row`, `position`, `detector_0`...`detector_251`.

В `position` данные:27939 - 34929. Внутри колонок `detector_0`...`detector_251` разброс 0 и 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


path = 'D:/Working/csv_CDL/run1_CD90-20,2_data.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')
dr = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:, 1:2])                # 'position' (row 6991 (27939m - 34929m))
dp = data.iloc[:, 2:]                               # 'detector_0 ... detector_n' (0-251)
dp.replace('--', np.NAN, inplace=True)              # '--' ->  bool
dt = dp.isnull()
_dt = dt.replace({False: 1, True: 0})
df = pd.concat([dr, _dt], axis=1, join='inner')     # объединяем в один DataFrame (6991 rows x 253 columns)


plt.scatter(df.columns[:1], df.columns[1:], s=5, color='red', marker='o')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример входных и выходных данных а ещё лучше привести ссылку на ваши данные на каком-нибудь файлообменнике?

Comment: На выходе хотелось бы что-то вроде этого https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_formatstr.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-formatstr-py.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду вы пытаетесь нарисовать **наименования столбцов** Pandas DataFrame dв качестве точек на плоскости, причем передавая в качестве значений по осям `X` и `Y` различное колмчество элементов:

```
plt.scatter(df.columns[:1], df.columns[1:], s=5, color='red', marker='o')
```

Попытка воспроизведения ошибки:

```
In [51]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, size=(6,5)), columns=list('abcde'))

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   7  14  44  41  20
1   7  27  30  19  42
2  48  14  39  41  24
3  17  37  34  33  14
4  12  27  11  30   7
5  25  18  41  37  11

In [53]: plt.scatter(df.columns[:1], df.columns[1:], s=5, color='red', marker='o')
...
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

"разбор полётов":

в качестве значений по оси `X` вы передали:

```
In [54]: df.columns[:1]
Out[54]: Index(['a'], dtype='object')
```

в качестве значений по оси `Y`:

```
In [55]: df.columns[1:]
Out[55]: Index(['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

не удивительно, что `plt.scatter()` не понимает как начертить такие "точки"

---

Более правильный подход - допустим мы хотим начертить точки из приведенного выше примера таким образом, что столбец `a` задаёт координату по оси `X`, а столбец `b` по оси `Y`:

```
In [58]: df.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', s=5, color='red', marker='o', grid=True)
Out[58]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x16bd26de4a8>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/qeEYUDnmo6RM-w - входные параметры. 0 - красным, 1 - синим для графика https://yadi.sk/i/o7qlBQ4ai_1onQ

Comment: Вы слегка переоценили мое желание вам помочь, если подумали, что я брошусь "вбивать" ваши данные с картинки. ;-) Предполагая нечто подобное я оставил вам ссылку под вопросом в качестве комментария...

Comment: Вбивать ничего не нужно. Картинки, чтобы лучше объяснить, что мне требуется.

Comment: @СергейЕршов, как вы собираетесь различать точки принадлежащие 252 датчикам на одном графике?

Comment: Я думаю, собрать датчики и дистанции в отдельный DataFrame, где в ячейках будут одни единицы. Например, `dw = df[df['detector_0'] == 1]`

Comment: @СергейЕршов, т.е. вам не надо различать данные от различных датчиков и надо нарисовать все точки одним цветом?

Comment: В идеале надо, но это, как мне кажется, сложнее реализовать.

Comment: @СергейЕршов, вы не можете выложить свой CSV файл на файлообменник?

Comment: К сожалению, не могу. На работе СБ блокирует данную возможность. Если только я сам дома сгенерирую и выложу.